# Access CarrierWave image url using SQL in Rails migration

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm working on a small app that uses CarrierWave for image uploading, but (for reasons that are a bit long and not really relevant) we have to stop using CarrierWave and start uploading images with our own custom requests to different cloud storage services.

But I still need to have the URLs to images that were already uploaded using CarrierWave, and I won't have access to the `image_url` method once I unmount the CarrierWave uploader, so I want to save all the urls to a new column on my model, and to have that migration be as optimized as possible.

I've searched for ways to access directly the url from the database (I mean, CarrierWave has to store that *somewhere*) but no luck so far.

I could do something like this (`business_image` is the column that the uploader is mounted on, `image_url` is the new column where I want to store the url):

```
def change
  add_column :business_cards, :image_url, :string

  BusinessCard.all.each do |bc|
    bc.update(image_url: bc.business_image_url)
  end
end
```

But that is obviously not optimized at all since it loads all business cards and updates them one by one. Is there a way to do it in a single SQL statement?

(I'm using Rails 5.1.4, PostgreSQL 10.3 and carrierWave 1.2.1)

Comment: The only way is to implement mounter logic is SQL query. I.e. if you have simple mounter logic like `'business_card' + '/id/' + image_name` you can implement it in SQL.

Comment: It may be sufficient to keep this logic of going "one at a time", and just leaving it to run for a long time? (It depends how big the database is!!) But instead of using `all`, use [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each). This prevents loading all records into memory at once.

Comment: But yes, as @PavelMikhailyuk said the URLs are dependant on the carrierwave uploader definition. How are they defined in `app/uploaders/*`? You can write some bulk update SQL based on this.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I had no idea CarrierWave reconstructs the URL from config values instead of saving it in a database. The carrierwave uploader configuration is not quite that simple, but since my database is not too large (about 3000 records), I'll do it using `find_each` as @TomLord recommended

Answer (score 0):

One way would be too use batch function and update record in batches, you can use transaction so that if there are any errors the changes would be rolled back.

```
def change
 add_column :business_cards, :image_url, :string

BusinessCard.find_each(batch_size: xxx) do |bc|

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
    bc.update(image_url: bc.business_image_url)
rescue => e
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

end
end
```

Hope it helps!!